# Parameterizing using Regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to implement a c++ parser using boost and regex.
I need to be able to parse statements like the following:

```
parameters a1=bbb b a2=bbb   b  a3 =bbb
parameters  a4=b a5=bb
parameters a6=b  a7=[b b b]  aa8=b b b
```

For this input, the desired parameters would be:

```
a1=bbb b
a2=bbb   b
a3 =bbb
a4=b
a5=bb
a6=b
a7=[b b b]
aa8=b b b
```

Where a and b could be any of the following chars: A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%_\,;:|/&()-+*^.<> or the following patterns: (==)(<=)(>=)
The name of the parameter does not allow spaces, however, the value does.

I was trying the code below, but it does not work properly:

```
[A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+\s*=\s*([\sA-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+(?!(([\sA-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+)?\s*=\s*[\sA-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+))|[A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+|(\[[\sA-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+\]))
```

The pattern

```
[A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+\s*=\s*([A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+|(\[[\sA-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+\]))
```

works as far as the value does not contain spaces.
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Boost::Spirit. regex is not for parsing.

Comment: Parsing C++ is an insane amount of work. Unless you are doing it for learning pourposes I would recommend you to use [GCC-XML](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html). Also, don't use regex for that, you will fall in some "gotcha" sooner or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have finally found the answer to my problem. The expected regex was:

```
\w+\s*=\s*[\w\s]+(?=\s+\w+=)|\w+\s*=\s*[\w\s]+(?!\w+=)|\w+\s*=\s*\[[\w\s]+\]
```

Match all the param_name (\w+\s*), all the param_value (\s*[\w\s]+ or [[\w\s]+] for listings).
This param_value ends where the next parameter_name starts (?=\s+\w+=), or at the end of the sentence if it is not followed by another parameter (?!\w+=).

All supported characters have been replaced by \w for shorten the answer.

Thanks to all of the people who had answered, specially to @pobrelkey who told me the right direction in which I needed to focus.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in boost, but the following should work:

```
((?:[A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%_\\,;:|/&()\-+*^\.<>]|==|<=|>=)+)\s*=\s*((?:[A-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%_\\,;:|/&()\-+*^\.<>\s]|==|<=|>=)+)
```

Note that by your rules line `a7` doesn't parse.

Comment: Thanks @pobrelkey, but this patter does not work in my example, it gets the following matches:

     a1=bbb b a2
     a4=b a5
...

Instead of

    a1=bbb b
    a2=bbb   b
    .....

I have tried both in c++/boost and grep -P.

Related to the listings a7=[b b b] I try solve it by using

    (\[[\sA-Za-z0-9çÇñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ@%\_\\\,\;\:\|\/\&\(\)\-\+\*\^\.(==)\>\<(\<=)(\>=)]+\])

In the second part of the pattern, (affter \s*=\s*), and it seems to work.